# something wrong with replace string?

Tags: php, html, dynamic

Can anyone help me with this:

```
<?php
$remove = $_GET['hwid'];
str_replace($_GET['hwid']."<br />","",$str);
?>
```

It doesnt even delete the text...

I Know i dont have it set to the html file i have thats because i don't know how to with this string...

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?  [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) may be a good place to start looking.

Comment: Seriously please try to make some effort to format well in the future, that was an eyesore, italics aren't meant to be used on EVERYTHING...

Comment: how do i use the  `str_replace()`

Comment: @user2364242 You obviously have no idea what you are doing. You should probably go learn some PHP before asking questions.

Comment: The point here is that `str_replace` doesn't alter what you pass in, but instead _returns_ the result of the replacement.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have this as you retrieved text (whether from html or any other form):

```
$str="THE HTML FILE:

Test

Test1

Test2

Test3";
```

this function will remove "Test2" from the string:

```
$newstr=str_replace("Test2","",$str);
```

for more information of the function take a look at [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Just one more thing, if you have `<br>` after each line in your example, you need to do the same for those too.