# Is there something wrong with my php code?

Tags: php

> **This question already has an answer here:**
>   [something wrong with replace string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473300/something-wrong-with-replace-string)  *1 answer*

Ok so i have my php code:

```
<?php
$str="hwids.html"
str_replace($_GET['hwid']."<br />","",$str);
?>
```

and when i go to the html script after running the php script, the text is still there that i told it to remove

Can anyone help?

Comment: it's unclear what your asking for. there are syntax errors, and a bit of code that doesn't really do anything. what are you trying to do?

Comment: If you could tell us what you're trying to do, we could help you. What is the output you're expecting?

Comment: @Samuel Cook im trying to put in a value for hwid, then when i do that, it will replace a text/code inside the html  with the value i put in for hwid, that i picked... The output im looking for is it to remove the text it had that i want it to get replaced with("")

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of one of your earlier questions.

Comment: @scrblnrd3 please post duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot semicolon

```
$str="hwids.html";
```

But your HTML script should not change cause you are making replace just in the string `"hwids.html"`

Correct solution in your case:

```
$file = 'hwids.html';
file_put_contents($file,str_replace($_GET['hwid']."<br />",'',file_get_contents($file)));
```

Comment: nope, the text is still there for some reason...

Comment: well how could i get the html code to update...

Comment: @zavg answered the question you asked what you are looking for is file handling in php try http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file.asp and take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: @Melternet dont forget to select as best answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$str="hwids.html
```

This needs to become

```
$str="hwids.html;
```

Don't forget semicolons.

You have several other syntax issues. What output are you trying to receive? That should help clarify what your error is.

Comment: zavg answered my question, thanks anyways